# Error while uploading File using CSOM C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, development, document-library

I am uploading a file to a SharePoint Online document library from a byte array and on execution I am getting the error "File Not found"

```
public static bool UploadFile(SP sp, string folderName, string fileNameWithExtension, byte[] fileContent, TraceWriter log)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {       
        SecureString securePwd = new SecureString();
        char[] pwdarray = sp.pwd.ToCharArray();

        foreach (var item in pwdarray)
        {
            securePwd.AppendChar(item);
        }

        SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(sp.id, securePwd);

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sp.url))
        {
            log.Info("UploadToSharePoint 1");

            clientContext.Credentials = creds;
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;           

            var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
            fileCreationInformation.Content = fileContent;
            fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;          

            fileCreationInformation.Url = fileNameWithExtension;            
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("All Attachments");
            docs.RootFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);           
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();          
            return result = true;    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, which works fine in my environment:

```
static void UploadFiles(string siteUrl, string userName, string password, string targetLibrary, string filePath)
        {
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1. Connecting to SharePoint Online....");

                bool isOffice365 = false;
                Boolean.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsOffice365"], out isOffice365);
                if (isOffice365)
                {
                    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);

                    SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                    context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
                }
                else
                {

                }

                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(targetLibrary);
                context.Load(list.RootFolder);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("2. Reading all folders from FileSystem...");
                string[] allDirectories = GetFolders(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine("\tFound {0} folders...", allDirectories.Count());

                Console.WriteLine("3. Looping each folder...");
                int folderCount = 0;

                #region -- Folders --
                foreach (string folderPath in allDirectories)
                {
                    folderCount++;
                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
                    string fileSystemRelativePath = folderPath.Replace(filePath, "");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}. Processing {1} folder...", folderCount, fileSystemRelativePath);

                    string folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileSystemRelativePath.Replace('\\', '/'));
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t1. Verifying the path \"{0}\" in SharePoint..", folderRelativeUrl);
                    Folder spoFolder = GetFolderByRelativeUrl(context.Web, folderRelativeUrl);

                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t2. Creating folder \"{0}\" in SharePoint if not exists...", folderRelativeUrl);
                    if (spoFolder == null)
                    {
                        spoFolder = CreateFolder(context.Web, list, folderRelativeUrl, di.Name);
                    }

                    if (spoFolder != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t3. Reading files from Folder {0}...", fileSystemRelativePath);
                        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tFound {0} files...", sourceFiles.Count());

                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t4. Uploading files to SharePoiont...");
                        int fileCount = 0;

                        foreach (string sourceFile in sourceFiles)
                        {
                            fileCount++;
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
                            string fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", spoFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);
                            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t{0}. Processing {1}...", fileCount, fileUrl);
                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tFolder creating failed or could not found the folder...");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                } 
                #endregion
                Console.WriteLine("4. Processing files in root folder");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t1. Reading files from Folder {0}...", filePath);
                string[] rootFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tFound {0} files...", rootFiles.Count());

                Console.WriteLine("\t\t1. Uploading files to SharePoiont...");

                int rootfilesCount = 0;
                foreach (string rootFilePath in rootFiles)
                {
                    rootfilesCount++;
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(rootFilePath);
                    string fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t{0}. Processing {1}...", rootfilesCount, fileUrl);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(rootFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The source code is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bhumi/2016/07/13/upload-files-from-filesystem-to-sharepoint-online-using-csom/)